# Memory Leak Test

Tags: ios, swift, memory-leaks

I have a class named PERSON to test memory leak. Here are the contents of class:

```
let name: String
private var actionClosure: (() -> ())!

init (name: String) {
    self.name = name
    self.actionClosure = {
        println("I am \(self.name)")
    }
}

func performAction () {
    actionClosure()
}

deinit {
    println("\(name) is being deinitialized")
}
```

Anyway, the book I am following wrote a code inside ViewController.swift. Beneath the viewDidLoad() method. Here are contents:

`let person = Person(name: "randomName"); person.performAction();`

The part I didn't understand is this: We initialize something with String. I get it but how does the class directly becomes able to use this? Like how does it know to take that init? I really didn't understand what happened there. It would be awesome if someone can explain the class and what happened in it.

Comment: That's Swift code, not Objective-C.

Answer (score 1):

Inside the `Person` class you have defined an initialiser which accepts `String` as the parameter.

```
init (name: String)
```

Try adding another initialiser like this

```
init (name: String) {

    self.name = name

    self.actionClosure = {

        println("I am \(self.name)")

    }

}

init(someOtherName: String) {
    self.name = someOtherName

    self.actionClosure = {

        println("I am \(self.name)")

    }
}
```

With this you have defined two initialisers and you can call either the original one like

```
let person = Person(name: "randomName")
```

or you can call

```
let person = Person(someOtherName: "randomName")
```

and they will perform the same initialisation. I hope this answers your question

Answer (score 1):

Your `Person` object will leak because you have a "strong reference cycle". The class owns `actionClosure` (i.e. has a strong reference to it), but `actionClosure` has a strong reference back to `self`.

Your closure should use `weak` or `unowned` reference to `self` to break this strong reference cycle:

```
self.actionClosure = { [unowned self] in 
    println("I am \(self.name)")
}
```

That will resolve the strong reference cycle.

---

You asked "how does it know to take that `init`?" It knows which `init` to call on the basis of the names and types of the parameters you provide.

Consider your, `init` implemented as follows:

```
init (name: String) { ... }
```

That takes a `name` parameter of type `String`. So, to instantiate the object in such a way that it uses that `init` method, you would use the class name, e.g. `Person`, with a parameter called `name` which is of type `String`, e.g.:

```
let person = Person(name: "Rob")
```

See the [Initialization](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Initialization.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH18-ID203) chapter of *The Swift Programming Language* guide.